# Case Study: Kashrut of Tapioca Starch

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, hechsher-certification

I have heard different answers from representatives of the cRc and the Star-K regarding the kashrut of un-certified tapioca starch. While both agree that it requires a hechsher for Pessach, the Star-K indicates that it doesn't otherwise, whereas the cRc states that it always needs to bear a reliable kashrut indicator.

While I am not asking who is correct (that would be off-topic, as it relates to psak) I wonder how two of the three major American hechsherim can come to such radically different conclusions on such a comparatively-simple ingredient.*

Is there any exploration behind this particular type of machloket in contemporary kashrut ?

---

*"Simple" is a relative term, as some "simple" ingredients do indeed require a hechsher at all times, whereas others either never do or necessitate only on Pessach.

Comment: -1. Firstly, it's not such a radically different conclusion - they both agree about pesach, and are only disputing policy year-round. 
2. There is likely some factor related to processing that one is concerned about. A simple Google search can find details of processing that would indeed be concerning. 3. Also, these should be questions for the organizations themselves, not us...

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://earthkosher.com/kosher-certification-starches/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwiHsruAue_iAhXPc98KHSjYDxkQFjALegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0hYtlm37Yf4o47cy8403Ue&ampcf=1